# Fix for wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, content-management-system

I am new too wordpress and have one problem. I finaly understand post loop and it work well but have one problem. For example: I have two pages of my posts (all are 6). In one page i have five posts (excerpt only) and on secound page i have one post only and in this case (when on one of my pages i have only one post it change to content post but it need to stay excerpt). So my question is what can i change in my code to make it work well in this case when on some page left only one post?

It's my loop:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

  <?php if (($wp_query->post_count) > 1) : ?>
     <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <!-- Do your post header stuff here for excerpts-->
          <?php the_excerpt() ?>
       <!-- Do your post footer stuff here for excerpts-->
     <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php else : ?>

     <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <!-- Do your post header stuff here for single post-->
          <?php the_content() ?>
       <!-- Do your post footer stuff here for single post-->
     <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
     <!-- Stuff to do if there are no posts-->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the posts_per_page parameter to an array and start the loop.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 4,'category' => 2, 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  $content = get_the_content();
  echo $content;
endwhile;
```

Here I have printed the 4 contents from the archive. So the page will only have 4 posts in it. You can change the value based on your need.

I have used and got the output. Hope this helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Ur second if condition should be inside while and while shuld be called once ..
Somthing like 
If 
   While 
      Then if for count
           Elseif
                Else
End while
End if

I hope it wil help ..

Comment: Thank you for message but thame don't work when i made it. Can you show it on the loop example?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for all: `$wp_query->post_count` need to be replaced by `$wp_query->found_posts` and everything working fine now!